# UIAccelerometerDelegate: can i have two objects to handle DidAccelerate event?

Tags: ios, delegates, uiaccelerometer

I am porting my android App to iOS, and have a little trouble with accelerometer. I want to have two different classes, that have DidAccelerate implementation. I make two objects, each becomes a delegate for UIAccelerometer. But only one object - that was created last, works. The other one do not get event from accelerometer. UIAccelerometer can not have two delegates working in the same time in one application?

Answer (score 1):

I would make your view controller the main delegate for the accelerometer and then have that implementation pass the data on to any other concerned parties:

```
- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration {

    /* So just create a couple properties to hold an instance of your other delegates. */
    [self.accelerometerDelegate1 accelerometer:accelerometer didAccelerate:acceleration];

    [self.accelerometerDelegate2 accelerometer:accelerometer didAccelerate:acceleration];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a [singleton](http://www.johnwordsworth.com/2010/04/iphone-code-snippet-the-singleton-pattern/) for that.